# Watershed Algorithm setting removing all connected components

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I'm using the watershed algorithm to try and segment touching nuclei. A typical image may look like:[image]
or this: [image]

I'm trying to apply the watershed algorithm with this code:

```
show(RGB_img)


%Convert to grayscale image
I = rgb2gray(RGB_img);

%Take structuring element of a disk of size 10, for the morphological transformations
%Attempt to subtract the background from the image: top hat is the
%subtraction of the open image from the original


%Morphological transformation to subtract background noise from the image
%Tophat is the subtraction of an opened image from the original. Remove all
%images smaller than the structuring element of 10
I1 = imtophat(I, strel('disk', 10));

%Increases contrast
I2 = imadjust(I1);
%show(I2,'contrast')
%Assume we have background and foreground and assess thresh as such 
level = graythresh(I2);
%Convert to binary image based on graythreshold
BW = im2bw(I2,level);
show(BW,'C');



BW = bwareaopen(BW,8);
show(BW,'C2');

BW = bwdist(BW) <= 1;
show(BW,'joined');
%Complement because we want image to be black and background white
C = ~BW;
%Use distance tranform to find nearest nonzero values from every pixel
D = -bwdist(C);

%Assign Minus infinity values to the values of C inside of the D image
%   Modify the image so that the background pixels and the extended maxima
%   pixels are forced to be the only local minima in the image (So you could
%   hypothetically fill in water on the image

D(C) = -Inf;

%Gets 0 for all watershed lines and integers for each object (basins)
L = watershed(D);
show(L,'L');

%Takes the labels and converts to an RGB (Using hot colormap)
fin = label2rgb(L,'hot','w');

% show(fin,'fin');
im = I;

%Superimpose ridgelines,L has all of them as 0 -> so mark these as 0(black)
im(L==0)=0;

clean_img = L;
show(clean_img)
```

For whatever reason after `C = ~BW;` the whole image goes dark. This very same code block has worked on a handful of other images, all of which were more "solid" or not as grainy as these. However, I thought I compensated for this with `BW = bwdist(BW) <= 1;`. I've experimented a ton and I don't really know what's happening. Any help would be great!

Ps. this is the image after `BW = bwareaopen(BW,8);`
[image: Image description here]

Comment: BW = bwdist(BW) <= 1; leaves all the points with value 1 which are at most a distance of one pixel to another pixels with value 1. If you image is grainy it could be that the distace between points with value 1 are more than 1 and this line of code deletes them. how does the image BW looks like after this line of code?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani After removing that line, the image still goes dark? I'm not sure why, but it seems to be after `C = ~BW`. Thanks!

Comment: How does the image look like before BW = bwareaopen(BW,8);
and after?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani it looks spotty but what I'd expect- I added an update to the question with the image. Any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: Trying adding dilation before the the line BW = bwdist(BW) <= 1; . Add the lines: se = strel('diamond',5); imdilate(BW,se);

Comment: @AmitayNachmani That did make the circles more circular but I still end up with a black image after `D = -bwdist(C);`?

Comment: How do you look at the values of D by using imshow(D)? if yes it doesn't necessarily mean that the all the image is zero try to use: min(D(:)) and max(D(:)) and see what do you get

Comment: @amitayNachmani Oh wow, I looked into the matrix of D and there are actually a ton of smaller negative values, not just all negative infinities. Is there a way to view this or handle it better- maybe converting to positives? I also tried `show(min(D(:))` and got a single pixel, am I just writing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Before the top-hat, you should perform a closing and an opening in order to reduce the noise.

If you perform an area opening on a noisy image, you may end up with the result on your black and white image.

So it would be:

1. Closing and opening
2. Top-Hat
3. Area opening if still necessary
4. Thresholding
5. Erosion and dilation to find the inner and outer markers respectively
6. Watershed (never use a watershed without markers).